# GL_POINTS or quads fastest?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es

I'm working on a drawing app where there's a lot of textured points.

Just wondering if there's a speed difference between the two (i tried both and couldn't tell)

Thanks

Comment: "i tried both and couldn't tell" - did you benchmark?

Comment: I think this question is too vague. Use case please?

Comment: @Mitch: not really, I just tested the app with point drawing and polygon drawing
@Xavier: I'm not looking for optimizations to specific code, just questioning in theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in theory, `GL_POINTS` should be the faster, simply since it's only one (x, y, z) triplet per rendered point, whereas for a quad you need to transfer four.

Comment: I think that's pretty valid, thanks.

I was just confused when i saw some posts on other forums blaming GL_POINTS for performance issues.